# Hotel reservation price code weekend price (Logic implementation issue)

Tags: c#, logic

I am trying to charge $30 more when a user book reservation for the day Friday and Saturday as the weekend extra charge, But I am not able to get the day and not able to add my extra charges.
I have done this so far:

```cs
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DateTime dtArrivalDate;
                DateTime.TryParse(txtArrivalDate.Text, out dtArrivalDate);
                DateTime dtDepartureDate;
                DateTime.TryParse(txtDepartureDate.Text, out dtDepartureDate);
                TimeSpan tsDuration = dtDepartureDate.Subtract(dtArrivalDate);
                int costPerNight = 120;
                for (DateTime date = dtArrivalDate; date <= dtDepartureDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
                {
                    DayOfWeek dw = date.DayOfWeek;
                    string days = dw.ToString();
                    int weekendCost = 0;
                    if (dw == DayOfWeek.Friday || dw == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    {
                        weekendCost = weekendCost + 30;
                        dw++;
                        int totalCost = tsDuration.Days * costPerNight + weekendCost;
                        int avgPricePerNight = (tsDuration.Days * costPerNight + weekendCost) / tsDuration.Days;
                        txtNights.Text = tsDuration.Days.ToString("n");
                        txtTotalPrice.Text = totalCost.ToString("n");
                        txtAvgPrice.Text = avgPricePerNight.ToString("n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int totalCost = tsDuration.Days * costPerNight;
                        int avgPricePerNight = (tsDuration.Days * costPerNight) / tsDuration.Days;
                        txtNights.Text = tsDuration.Days.ToString("n");
                        txtTotalPrice.Text = totalCost.ToString("n");
                        txtAvgPrice.Text = avgPricePerNight.ToString("n");
                    }
                }    
            }
```

Comment: I've removed your `[visual-studio-201]` tag because this question does not relate to Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you advise what issue you're seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DateTime date = dtArrivalDate; date <= dtDepartureDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
```

Not directly related to your problem, but that should be `date < dtDepartureData`.

Anyway, the problem is that you check each day, but inside the loop you recalculate and display the prices. Better code would be something like this (keeping your basic idea of iterating over each day):

```
int costPerNight = 120;
int weekendCost = 0;
for (DateTime date = dtArrivalDate; date < dtDepartureDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    DayOfWeek dw = date.DayOfWeek;
    if (dw == DayOfWeek.Friday || dw == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        weekendCost = weekendCost + 30;
    }
}
int totalCost = tsDuration.Days * costPerNight + weekendCost;
int avgPricePerNight = (tsDuration.Days * costPerNight + weekendCost) / tsDuration.Days;
txtNights.Text = tsDuration.Days.ToString("n");
txtTotalPrice.Text = totalCost.ToString("n");
txtAvgPrice.Text = avgPricePerNight.ToString("n");
```

We count each weekend day, then after the loop finishes, calculate up the total prices.

BTW, these `30` and `120` values should be replaced by named constants for better readability.